# The `set -o noclobber` prevents a file from being created using `echo Hello >> file.txt`

Tags: bash, zsh, io-redirection

I have used the

```bash
set -o noclobber
```

for many years in `.bashrc` or more recently, `.zshrc`.

However, I noticed that such as in the GitHub new repo instructions, the line

```bash
echo SomeName >> README.md
```

would fail if my `.zshrc` has this line `set -o noclobber`. It'd say:

```bash
zsh: no such file or directory: README.md
```

To confirm, I moved my `.zshrc` to `.zshrc_not_used` and start a new zsh, and then the line `echo SomeName >> README.md` would work when the `README.md` file doesn't exist.  But now if I start a new zsh and type in `set -o noclobber` and do `echo SomeName >> README_ANOTHER_ONE.md`, then it would say `README_ANOTHER_ONE.md` doesn't exist.

(the background info is that `>>` is to "append to", and to create the file when it doesn't exist.)

What is happening with this?  Naturally, I'd like to use `set -o noclobber` because I don't want to accidentally wipe out any file, but why does this `noclobber` have anything to do with `echo SomeName >> README.md` and it says `zsh: no such file or directory: README.md`. I tell the shell not to wipe something out, but instead it refused to create new content when it is not wiping out anything.

I actually remember it happening in Bash as well a couple of years ago, but right now I can't reproduce it.  Does someone know what is going on and what is a good solution to this?  (to solve the issue, not to manually type in `touch README.md` before `echo SomeName >> README.md`, because that would be "to fix it without knowing what is going on")

Comment: Why is this tagged bash, if it's purely a question about zsh behavior? zsh and bash are not mutually compatible in either direction, and never have claimed to be; indeed, willingness to be incompatible with POSIX-defined (or historically backwards-compatible) behaviors when zsh's implementors think those behaviors are bad ideas is perhaps the single most defining aspect of zsh.

Comment: that's because I had the same issue when I was using it on Bash, until a couple of years ago when MacBook changed their default shell to zsh

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is [documented](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-no-clobber_002c-POSIX-compatible) as a traditional behaviour of zsh (inherited from csh where `noclobber` comes from), set `appendcreate` (assuming zsh 5.1 or newer) in addition to `noclobber` to get the ksh / POSIX behaviour:

> `APPEND_CREATE <K> <S>`
>
> This option only applies when `NO_CLOBBER` (`-C`) is in effect.
>
> If this option is not set, the shell will report an error when a
> append redirection (`>>`) is used on a file that does not already
> exists (the traditional zsh behaviour of `NO_CLOBBER`). If the option
> is set, no error is reported (POSIX behaviour).

```
% set -o noclobber
% echo foo >> bar
zsh: no such file or directory: bar
% set -o appendcreate
% echo foo >> bar
% cat bar
foo
```

Comment: That's also the behaviour of csh where `noclobber` comes from. AFAIK, the Bourne shell didn't have an equivalent. `set -C` / `set -o noclobber` was added to ksh much later (ksh86 didn't have it).

Comment: `noclobber` was added to bash in 1.05 in 1990 initially as a *variable* (like in csh), not an option. It was initially preventing appending to existing files, changed soon after. AFAICT, it never prevented from appending to non-existing files. zsh had the noclobber option from the start (1.0 in 1990) and behave like csh and like today with regards to the append mode. [append_create was added in 5.1 for its POSIX mode](https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2015/msg01579.html).

Comment: You can use `>>!` to override this behavior as well. This is csh/tcsh/zsh specific Bash and zsh also accept `>>|` to do the same thing (csh/tcsh don't).

Comment: The Bourne shell indeed never had an equivalent option; this was a csh-ism from the start.